# My voice is genuinely being suppressed

Tags: discussion

It's a matter of common sense to understand that

1. Has Narender Modi's image in vaccination certificate been criticised by any international organisation or forum?
2. Do any other head of state print their own image in vaccination certificate except Narender Modi?

are different questions.

I am being suppressed here.

If it is not allowed, close it. However, tell me separately. It's not allowed straight. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure about your question here. From what I can see the second question was briefly mod-deleted (about a minute) as it seemed to be a duplicate of the first question which was closed by the community. It was undeleted by the same mod, presumably because the second question asks something else. I'm not sure what you're looking for with this meta question. The second question is no longer deleted but it has one pending close vote.

Comment: The same mod was being judgemental. Don't be. That's the point here.

Comment: The mod as already admitted they made a mistake there is no need to attack them and accuse them of being judgmental when they have undeleted your question and admitted they messed up.

Comment: You posted your comment that the mod was being judgmental after they had admitted to making a mistake and undeleting your question. There is no reason for you to continue to make accusations against them.

Comment: @JoeW I didn't notice. Anyways, accept the fact in the answer. It was a situation of haste. Lessons to be learnt. And yes, give her answer a "like". Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're right in that I was too hasty in my response to your post when I saw it pop up.

Your [second question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/66226/) was posted directly after your [first question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/66225/) was closed by the community, and given the similar topics, I made an error of judgement and assumed they were identical. After reading your post, I realised my mistake and reinstated your question. Your question was unavailable for sixty seconds.

With regards to your first question, this was closed because it doesn't appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about governments, policies and political processes as defined in the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

This is likely because of your use of terms such as "Pseudo-pro-democracy Narender Modi", and describing the same as a "hypocrite".

If you can reformulate your question to address this issue, it will automatically enter the reopen review queue, where the community will have a chance to reopen the question.